# Mimic Dynamics CRM Page

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, dynamics-crm

My client needs a custom page embedded into Microsoft Dynamics CRM. And this is no drama, it's essentially embedding an iFrame.

However ... he's pedantic and wants it to look like everything else in CRM.

Does anyone know of a Bootstrap CSS Theme that gets as close as possible to looking like CRM? I've searched and searched, but not luck.

Comment: The rendered CRM page will have a number of stylesheets attached to it. You can point linked styles in your iframe at those. But you will have to code your HTML the same way, e.g. classes, id's, etc.

Comment: Inspect the page with Browser dev toolbar, copy & store your own css files, bcoz using platform assets are not recommended (unsupported) & they will break in future when MS change it.

Comment: I agree. The easiest way is to copy OOB styles and store in your custom page. You can inspect it, rename for your oun markup, delete unnessesary. Or just create new css with the same combine properties.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a while since asked the question but host your custom pages in dynamics as Web Resources. And then use the dynamics default stylesheets like below. I think this is the easiest way.

[image]